# Excel VBA Macro - remove records older than a certain date and time

Tags: excel, vba

I'm very new to VBA etc. and having a bit of trouble getting a Macro to work for what I want from it.

I am trying to build a tool that will translate data received from a data extract to be in the format that I require.  I can run the import fine, however the challenge that I am having is that the extract will be pulled mutliple times a day with old records remaining on there.

The data has an assigned date and time, so I am hoping to build a rule that stores the latest assigned date and time from each macro run, and then the next time the macro is run, it will remove the records prior to that date and time.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Please post some code example of what you have done so far. Without it I can't say what needs to be changed...

Comment: In terms of removing records prior to a date and time, i'm at a start point with that.  This will be done before any of the other rules so is essentially independent of it.  I can add the rest if needs be, but it is a bit of a hatchet job so far.

Comment: You could just clear all the data before pulling in new data. `Thisworkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Cells.ClearContents`.  `Cells` refers to all cells on the sheet - you can change this to a range of cells to limit which ones will be cleared of data.

Comment: Hi Darren, Unfortunately the extract that gets pulled doesn't define what is new or what has been existing previously.  For example, if the extract gets pulled three times in a day, the same data would be on each extract.  The data gets imported in to another system, and i am looking to avoid data getting uploaded multiple times.